# Why can't I put 110 V appliances on 220 V outlets?

Tags: voltage

It's known that Power = voltage * current and it is also known that the voltage in the electric grid is fixed. So even though I know (from practical experience) that we cannot use 110 V devices on 220 V outlets, why does this happen? Shouldn't the electric current change in order to match the power required by the device?

Comment: It's well-known that heat energy = temperature x heat capacity and it is also known that the temperature in an oven is fixed. So why can't I cook twice as much food in a 360 degree oven as a 180 degree oven?

Comment: Would [electronics.se] be a better home for this question?

Comment: Sorry sir, I'm a newbie here at Stack Physics so I'm still getting used to the platform!

Comment: @user253751 That's a totally separate question and it has nothing to do with the OP. Plus, your statement about "heat energy" is related to temperature *change*, not temperature.

Comment: @BillN I think it helps illustrate how the thinking doesn't really make sense. You can't just say that because two things are multiplied, if one goes up then the other goes down

Answer (score 4):

Circuits designed specifically for 110V will have lower impedence. Plugging these into a 220V supply will have higher current and thus higher power. Components will either burn up or explode.

Power is not "required" by devices. Power consumption is a result of the voltage input and impedence of the device. The impedence (\$Z\$) is generally independent of the voltage and power is $$P=\frac{V^2}{Z}.$$

Some devices, such as transformers and switching power supplies have components designed to function properly over a large range of input voltage.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I haven't studied impedance yet, guess this will be the opportunity for leaning about it!

Comment: Impedence is similar to resistance, but it includes how capacitors and inductors (coils and transformers) interact with alternating current.

Comment: @GabrielOliveira, _Some_ devices will behave exactly as you said. They are modern, electronic gadgets that have _regulated_ (i.e., "smart") power supplies that can be plugged in to anywhere from about 100V to 250V, and they will draw only as much power as the device needs. Other devices (including pretty much everything made prior to the 21st century) are not so smart, and they will behave the way Bill N. described.

Answer (score 1):

There are some specific regulatory and engineering constraints on the voltage. For example if there is a transformer in the appliance that is supposed to raise the voltage to 1000 volts from 110, instead it goes to 2000 volts from 220. This could vastly exceed insulation limits in the appliance and you create a fire! You might note that the plug on the appliance is crafted specifically for the local supply and you would need to wire in an alternative, but did you manage the ground wire properly? More invitations for mayhem...